# How to suppress the backspace when the datefield calendar is active in extjs 4 especially in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, extjs

How can i restrict backspace in internet explorer for  datefield component when it is open/active state. Because when ever i pressed backspace after the datefield calendar opens, the current screen redirected to  previous page. so i want to restrict/suppress the backspace button when the calendar is active

[Click here for testing](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.form.field.Date.2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your Application launch function

```
Ext.getDoc().on('keydown', function (e, t) {
if (e.getKey() == e.BACKSPACE && (!/^input$/i.test(t.tagName) || t.disabled || t.readOnly)) {
            e.stopEvent();
        }
}); // Original answer was missing the closing parenthesis and semi
```

Answer (score 1):

When you open the calendar, its underlying date picker becomes active so this is where you need to prevent the backspace key:

See the fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/88a

```
            xtype: 'datefield',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'From',
            name: 'from_date',
            disableKeyFilter: true,
            maxValue: new Date(),
            listeners: {
                expand: function(field){
                    new Ext.util.KeyNav({
                        target: field.getPicker().getEl(),
                        scope: this,
                        backspace: {
                            fn: function(e){
                                e.stopEvent();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.getDoc().on('keydown', function (e, t) {
if (e.getKey() == e.BACKSPACE && (!/^input$/i.test(t.tagName) || t.disabled ||      t.readOnly)) {
        e.stopEvent();
    }
}); // Original answer missing closing parenthesis and semicolon...
```